# Creating a Keras Dataset form a Dask DataFrame (tensorflow_decision_forests)

Tags: python, dataframe, tensorflow, keras, dask

I am using Dask to load a pretty big dataset (way bigger than the available RAM I have), stored in a SQLite database, as shown below:

```
df = dd.read_sql_table("22", "sqlite:///db.sqlite", index_col="id")
```

Then, I want to use `tensorflow_decision_forests` to try to fit some models to the data. According to the documentation of `tensorflow_decision_forests`, the following should work for Pandas DataFrames:

```
import tensorflow_decision_forests as tfdf
train_ds = tfdf.keras.pd_dataframe_to_tf_dataset(df, label="species")
model = tfdf.keras.RandomForestModel()
model.fit(train_ds)
```

However, when I use `tfdf.keras.pd_dataframe_to_tf_dataset` in the Dask DataFrame, nothing happens for a very long time, and then python is terminated out of the blue with a `SIGTERM` signal. I am guessing that this is not the proper way of converting a Dask DataFrame to a Keras dataset, although no error/exception is thrown. What is the proper way of using data stored in Dask DataFrames from Keras? Specifically, what is the proper way of converting a Dask DataFrame to a Keras dataset?